Debugging Drizzle SQL query with undefined (reading 'referencedTable')
I'm have created a query with drizzle-orm and having an issue to debug it
const results = db.query.contract_opgc.findMany({
columns: {
  contract_id: true,
 ....

},
extras: {
  totalCount: sql<number>`COUNT(*) OVER()`.as('totalCount'),
},
where: (contract, { eq, and }) => and(eq(contract.country_code, countryCode)),
with: {
  item: {
    columns: {
      item_type_code: true,
    },
  },
},

I seems like there an issue with item and wrong table name but I think it's correct. How I can have this query as plain before processing by drizzle orm
Also I have added on top of this
 export const contractRelations = relations(item, ({ one }) => ({
  contract: one(contract, {
    fields: [item.item_gid, item.item_country_code],
    references: [contract.item_gid, contract.country_code],
  }),
}));


findMany has a toSQL, this will return you the sql and params that will be sent.

Unfortunately I think to SQL only works on correct defined SQL so you cannot debug it.
